# How do you add adjacent numbers in a list? I can't get the last variable

Tags: python, loops

Let `x = [3, 8, -2, 6, 9, -4, 7, 1, -5, 8]`

Use a for loop to add adjacent elements in `x`.
Store each of these results in a vector, `sa`.
Display both the vector x and the vector `sa`.
For example, the first 3 numbers of `sa` will be:

```
sa = [11, 9, 12, …]  = [(3+8), (3+8+(-2)), (8+(-2)+6), …]
```

I have something like this...

```
x = [3, 8, -2, 6, 9, -4, 7, 1, -5, 8]
sa = []

for i in range (0, len(x)-1):
    if i<1:
        sa.append(x[0] + x[1])
    elif i >= 1 & i< len(x):
        sa.append(x[i-1] + x[i] + x[i+1])
    if i == 0:
        sa.append(x[i] + x[i+1])
print("Here is sa", sa)
```

but I can't get the last variable of -5 +8 to appear please help
what I end up getting is 
Here is `sa`, `[11, 11, 9, 12, 13, 11, 12, 4, 3, 4]`
but I also need the last value it should be (-5+8)= 3 so the total final answer should include the three like

```
[11, 11, 9, 12, 13, 11, 12, 4, 3, 4, 3]
```

or even

```
[11, 9, 12, 13, 11, 12, 4, 3, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Hey William, could you edit your question to mention exactly what does happen when you run your code?

Comment: You can use vectors in C++.

Comment: @DavidSmolinski this question is about Python...

Comment: You can also use numpy to get vectors.

Comment: @DavidSmolinski or you can just use a python list... which is essentially the equivalent of a C++ vector. `numpy`  actually provides true multidimensional arrays, unlike C++ vectors, which I believe would use "vectors of vectors"

Comment: William wanted to use vectors. You can also use functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a+b,x)

Comment: @DavidSmolinski what? I'm pretty sure the OP is speaking informally, in any case, *a list is essentially the equivalent to a C++ vector type*, so no need for C++ or numpy even if you want "vectors"

Answer (score 2):

You can write this as a list comprehension, noting the `i`th element in `sa` is the `sum` of the `x` values from `x[i-1]` to `x[i+1]`. Now those indexes may overrun the boundaries of `x`, so we need to use `max` and `min` to keep them in range:

```
x = [3, 8, -2, 6, 9, -4, 7, 1, -5, 8]

sa = [sum(x[max(i-1, 0):min(i+2, len(x))]) for i in range(len(x))]
print(sa)
```

Output:

```
[11, 9, 12, 13, 11, 12, 4, 3, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you are looking for non comprehensive way, here it is.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if i == 0:
        sa.append(x[i] + x[i+1])
    elif 1 <= i < len(x)-1:
        sa.append(x[i-1] + x[i] + x[i+1])
    else:
        sa.append(x[i] + x[i-1])

print("Here is sa", sa)
```

Output:

```
Here is sa [11, 9, 12, 13, 11, 12, 4, 3, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some mistakes:

```
x = [3, 8, -2, 6, 9, -4, 7, 1, -5, 8]
sa = []

# the last element of the loop will be x[len(x)-2], it is -5 in this case
# -5 is the last element this loop process, it adds up 1, -5 and 8
# this loop will not take 8 as the central number, so the results miss the last value
for i in range (0, len(x)-1):
    if i<1:
        sa.append(x[0] + x[1])
    # in python, it is `and` not &, & is bitwise and.
    elif i >= 1 & i< len(x):
        sa.append(x[i-1] + x[i] + x[i+1])
    if i == 0: # this is meaningless, i == 0 is covered in the first if branch
        sa.append(x[i] + x[i+1])
print("Here is sa", sa)
```

Fix your code:

```
x = [3, 8, -2, 6, 9, -4, 7, 1, -5, 8]
sa = []

# fix one: loop to the last element
for i in range (0, len(x)):
    if i<1:
        sa.append(x[0] + x[1])
    # fix two: do not include the last element in this elif branch
    elif i >= 1 and i < len(x) - 1:
        sa.append(x[i-1] + x[i] + x[i+1])
    # fix three: process the last element.
    else:
        sa.append(x[i - 1] + x[i])
print("Here is sa", sa)
```

output:

```
Here is sa [11, 9, 12, 13, 11, 12, 4, 3, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [3, 8, -2, 6, 9, -4, 7, 1, -5, 8]
```

Create a list with the sum of the first two elements,

```
>>> q = [sum(x[:2])]
```

Iterate over the list three at a time and append the sums.

```
>>> for thing in zip(x,x[1:],x[2:]):
...     q.append(sum(thing))
```

Append the sum of the last two items.

```
>>> q.append(sum(x[-2:]))

>>> q
[11, 9, 12, 13, 11, 12, 4, 3, 4, 3]
```