# Summing up neighbors numbers

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to iterate over all numbers in my list and I want to sum each number with his neighbor.

```
    DataList=[2,7,18,22]
    total=0
    for number in DataList:
        total+=number
    print(DataList[0] + DataList[1])
    print(DataList[0] + DataList[1]+DataList[2])
    print(DataList[1] + DataList[2]+DataList[3])
    print(DataList[2] + DataList[3])

#Output from code above
9
27
47
40
```

As you can see from code above I already made some solution but this solution is not good (in realistic I have very big sample) because I typed all commands with print, so can anybody help me how to solve this problem and make automatic loop and make sum over all neighbors numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add adjacent numbers in a list? I can't get the last variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61298291/how-do-you-add-adjacent-numbers-in-a-list-i-cant-get-the-last-variable)

Comment: when you say you want to sum each number with its neighbors, you want to sum only to the right? Also how come you dont want a value for all items assuming you start with position 0. Then all items 0 thru 3 should be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a mix of `if-elif-else` with loop as:

```
DataList=[2,7,18,22]
for i in range(len(DataList)):
    if i == 0:
        print(DataList[i] + DataList[i+1])
    elif i == len(DataList)-1:
        print(DataList[i-1] + DataList[i])
    else:
        print(DataList[i-1] + DataList[i] + DataList[i+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in itertools which is accumulate it is actually functioning as you want. This is the python docs you can find accumulate here https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 1):

```
DataList=[2,7,18,22]
xp=[items for item in [[sum(DataList[:x+1]),sum(DataList[x:])]for x in range(len(DataList))] for items in item]
print(xp)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP's question correctly as it doesn't account for the left neighbor in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you intend to have:

```
totalNum = len(DataList)
totalSum = 0
sumArray = [0]*totalNum

for i in range(totalNum):
    sumArray[i] += DataList[i]
    if i+1 < totalNum:
        sumArray[i] += DataList[i+1]
    if i-1 > 0:
        sumArray[i] += DataList[i-1]
for i in range(totalNum):
    print(sumArray[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

A "clever" way to do it would be to create three versions of the list with `0`'s appended, them sum them up.

```py
DataList = [ 2, 7, 18, 22 ]

l = [ 0, 0 ] + DataList
c = [ 0 ] + DataList + [ 0 ]
r = DataList + [ 0, 0 ]

sums = [ sum( n ) for n in zip( l, c, r ) ]
```

You can then slice the elements off the ends if you don't want them.

Using this approach you can also use `numpy` to speed of the calculation for large lists.

```py
sums = np.sum( np.array( [ l, c, r ] ), axis = 0 )
```

For different sized lists you can see the `numpy` payoff (note y-axis is in log scale)
[image: Timing comparison of list and numpy neighbor sums.]